# Loop adding key and value to dictionary using for loop .splitlines

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to read a string and add the first line as a key to a dictionary and the second as a value until the end of the file.
So 1 to key,2 to value, 1 to key,2 to value, 1 to key,2 to value... 
until the end of the file.

Im trying to add keys and values from a string.
When I write 8 loops it works fine but I want to only use one loop.
here is the 8 loop example that works.

```
tmp_dic = {}

String = "First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth\nFifth\nSixth\nSeventh\nEight"


for x in String.splitlines()[0:1:]:
    print(x)
    x2 = x
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    for y in String.splitlines()[1:2:]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"

for x in String.splitlines()[2:3:]:
    print(x)
    x2 = x
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    for y in String.splitlines()[3:4:]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"

for x in String.splitlines()[4:5:]:
    print(x)
    x2 = x
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    for y in String.splitlines()[5:6:]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"

for x in String.splitlines()[6:7:]:
    print(x)
    x2 = x
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    for y in String.splitlines()[7:8:]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"

print(tmp_dic)
```

The print output is correct:

```
First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
Sixth
Seventh
Eight
```

And the dictionary is good too.

```
{'First': 'Second', 'Third': 'Fourth', 'Fifth': 'Sixth', 'Seventh': 'Eight'}
```

Here is the one loop example

```
tmp_dic = {}

String = "First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth\nFifth\nSixth\nSeventh\nEight"


c1 = 0
c2 = 1


for x in String.splitlines()[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]:
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    c1 = c1 + 1
    c2 = c2 + 1
    for y in String.splitlines()[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"
        c1 = c1 + 1 
        c2 = c2 + 1
print(tmp_dic)
```

Im getting the following Error. But c1 and c2 are both integers.

```
  File "testdic3.py", line 12, in <module>
    for x in String.splitlines()[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I also tried:

```
tmp_dic = {}

String = "First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth\nFifth\nSixth\nSeventh\nEight"


lengh = len(String.splitlines())

c1 = 0
c2 = 1

for I in range(lengh):
    x = String.splitlines()[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]:
    tmp_dic[f"{x}"] = f""
    c1 = c1 + 1
    c2 = c2 + 1
    for y in String.splitlines()[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]:
        print(y)
        tmp_dic[f"{x2}"] = f"{y}"
        c1 = c1 + 1
        c2 = c2 + 1

print(tmp_dic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is oddly phrased.
You might want to add a sentence to your question that explains the high-level motivation.

Assume we assign `lines = String.splitlines()`

Then what you want is simply `lines[c1:c2]`,
rather than `lines[f"{c1}":f"{c2}":]`.

(It would be fine to use `lines[c1:c2:]`,
but stepsize defaults to `1` so there's no need.
You might specify it when reversing, e.g. `lines[c2:c1:-1]`.)

> But c1 and c2 are both integers.

True enough. But once you've turned them into strings
(with an f-string formatter)
then you can't use them for slicing (or subscripting) any more.

Also, [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you name your variable `string` rather than `String`.
We use initial capital for a `class` rather than for such a temp var.

EDIT

When you google for something,
you just *assume* it exists already,
and you describe what the thing you want looks like.
Works like magic!

When writing a program,
you can make a similar assumption.
You said you want (key, value) pairs.
Ok, fair enough, let's just pretend there is
*already* a function that offers them:

```
def populate_dictionary():
    d = {}

    for k, v in get_pairs():
        d[k] = v

    return d
```

Well, that was easy!
But wait, now we have to return to the hard part,
we'll need a `get_pairs()` definition.
The nice thing is, now we're solving a **smaller** sub-problem,
it's much easier:

```
def get_pairs(input='First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth\nFifth\nSixth\nSeventh\nEight'):
    lines = input.splitlines()
    for i in range(len(lines) // 2):
        yield lines[2 * i], lines[2 * i + 1]
```

Ta-da! And now we're done.
(Sure, you could use a temp var like `c1`
if you prefer to avoid the fancy `2 * i` expression.)
It produces this output:

```
{'First': 'Second',
 'Third': 'Fourth',
 'Fifth': 'Sixth',
 'Seventh': 'Eight'}
```

(One could replace the `for` loop with `d.update(get_pairs())`,
or even more simply by assigning `d = dict(get_pairs())`,
but it appears you were looking for practice with the `for` statement.)

Comment: I added an explanation of what im trying to do just now. I just fixed the Naming convention from String to Content throughout my code.